# could not broadcastと表示される

Tags: python, numpy

画像診断のプログラムを組みたいのですが、下記のようなエラーが出てしまいます。
google colaboratoryを使用しており、kaggleのChest X-Ray Images (Pneumonia)というデータセットから何枚かgoogleドライブにアップロードして使おうとしています。
画像はグレースケールです。

参考にした動画ではカラー画像を使っていたので、それが関係しているのかもしれませんが、直し方が分かりません。どなたか教えていただけるとありがたいです。

[Pythonによるディープラーニングの作り方〜画像認識〜【Python機械学習入門#10】](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThKRS7B5GFY&t=1666s)

**エラーメッセージ**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-c83072b43715> in <module>()
     24 
     25 
---> 26 x_train = np.array(x_train) / 255.0
     27 y_train = np.array(y_train)
     28 x_test = np.array(x_test) / 255.0

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (100,100,1) into shape (100,100)
```

**ソースコード**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import glob

x_train = []
y_train = []
x_test = []
y_test = []



for f in glob.glob("/content/drive/MyDrive/kaggle/image/*/*/*.jpeg"):
    img_data = tf.io.read_file(f)
    img_data = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img_data)
    img_data = tf.image.resize(img_data,(100,100))
  
    if f.split("/")[6]=="train":
      x_train.append(img_data)
      y_train.append(int(f.split("/")[7].split("_")[0]))
    elif f.split("/")[6]=="test":
          x_test.append(img_data)
          y_test.append(int(f.split("/")[7].split("_")[0]))


x_train = np.array(x_train) / 255.0
y_train = np.array(y_train)
x_test = np.array(x_test) / 255.0
y_test = np.array(y_test)
```

Comment: Google Colaboratoryでやっているようですが、Windows上でtensorflow-cpu 2.8.0とnumpy 1.22.2だと動くかもしれません。venv等使えば環境構築は簡単でしょうし、実験するだけなのでデータは5～6個用意すれば良いでしょうから、まず試してみてはどうでしょう？

Answer (score 1):

似たような事例を見つけました。

[ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,224,3) into shape (224,224)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43977463)

以下のようにした際に、同じエラーが見られます。

```
a=np.random.rand(100,100,1)
b=np.random.rand(100,100)
c=[a,b]
c=np.array(c)
```

元のファイルを使って調べてみないと断言はできませんが、違うサイズのimg_dataが混ざっているのではないでしょうか。